# What is stackmap table in jvm bytecode?

Tags: java, bytecode

I am learning ASM library for generating bytecode. At some point I made some mistake with bad local variable type and got an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Bad local variable type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    Loops.start()V @56: aload_1
  Reason:
    Type top (current frame, locals[1]) is not assignable to reference type


  Stackmap Table:
    full_frame(@24,{Object[#2],Object[#9]},{Integer})
    full_frame(@25,{Object[#2],Object[#9]},{Integer,Integer})
    same_locals_1_stack_item_frame(@44,Integer)
    full_frame(@45,{Object[#2],Object[#9]},{Integer,Integer})
    full_frame(@48,{Object[#2]},{Integer})
    full_frame(@80,{Object[#2],Integer},{Integer})
    full_frame(@81,{Object[#2],Integer},{Integer,Integer})
    full_frame(@87,{Object[#2]},{Integer})
    full_frame(@119,{Object[#2],Integer},{Integer})
    full_frame(@120,{Object[#2],Integer},{Integer,Integer})
    same_locals_1_stack_item_frame(@123,Integer)
```

The problem was not difficult to find and fix but I'm curious what is a this stackmap table thing?

Answer (score 11):

[`StackMapTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.4) is an attribute in classes compiled with Java 6 or higher. It is used by the JVM during the process of [verification by type checking](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.1).

Basically, a stack map frame defines the expected types of local variables and the operand stack (i.e. the state of the frame) of a method during its execution. During run-time, The JVM throws the `VerifyError` if expected and actual types are incompatible.

To save space, not every instruction has a corresponding frame. The table only defines frames for potential jump targets or exception handlers. Other frames can be easily inferred from these ones. You can see in your table above that frames are defined only for some bytecode offsets.

Comment: Yeah, basically it's a "feature" that Sun added because their verifier was painfully slow and they were too dense to see any other way to speed it up.

Comment: Does garbage collector use this table to check if a local variable is a reference? I found out, that the bytecode can mix the types. For example: you can have ASTORE_1 and ISTORE_1 in the same method. And it still works.

Comment: @HotLicks How many class verifiers have you written in your life?