# How to read this information?

Tags: java, exception

I'm facing the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/company/MyClass.getProperty(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object; @93: ireturn
  Reason:
    Type integer (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'java/lang/Object' (from method signature)
  Current Frame:
    bci: @93
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/company/MyClass', 'java/lang/String', 'java/lang/String' }
    stack: { integer }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2b01 a600 0812 8da7 0007 2bb6 0090 4d2c
    0x0000010: b600 94ab 0000 0064 0000 0007 9a7f 0d13
    0x0000020: 0000 005f 9b27 5edf 0000 004b 0000 fc71
    0x0000030: 0000 0041 0023 a6ed 0000 005a 03b3 b10f
    0x0000040: 0000 0046 34ad f045 0000 0055 7a92 a99e
    0x0000050: 0000 0050 2ab6 0096 b02a b600 98ac 2ab6
    0x0000060: 009a b02a b600 9cb0 2ab6 009e b02a b600
    0x0000070: a0b0 2ab6 00a2 b0bb 0079 59bb 007b 59b7
    0x0000080: 007c 12a4 b600 822c b600 82b6 0086 b700
    0x0000090: 88bf                                   
  Stackmap Table:
    same_frame(@10)
    same_locals_1_stack_item_frame(@14,Object[#101])
    append_frame(@84,Object[#101])
    same_frame(@89)
    same_frame(@94)
    same_frame(@99)
    same_frame(@104)
    same_frame(@109)
    same_frame(@114)
    same_frame(@119)

at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
```

What does Bytecode, Stackmap Table sections mean? How can I interpret them ?

Comment: It means that the class file is invalid. In this particular case, the method returns something that its signature does not allow. How did you compile this class?

Comment: @Thilo The class was generated on the fly by javassist.

Comment: Maybe that is a bug in that tool or how it is used. But what you have here is a method with return type `Object` that tries to return an `int` (using the `ireturn` instruction). Any autoboxing has to be inserted at compile-time (maybe that part is missing in your code generation?), the resulting bytecode types have to match.

Comment: @Thilo Thanks for your help. I'll check this.

Comment: @Thilo However, the exception is thrown when the JVM tries to load the class (  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348))

Comment: Yes, when Java loads a class, it verifies the bytecode first before running anything. This is part of the security mechanism provided by Java. (In your case, it can statically check that this method would return something invalid by just looking at the code, without running it -- and then rejects the whole class as corrupted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a breakdown for the entire message:

---

```
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
```

This tells you what the exception is(`java.lang.VerifyError`) and the error message associated with it(`Bad return type`). You can use the exception type to determine a basic understanding for what the exception is(for example, if it were a `NullPointerException`, you can tell there was some sort of null object that was referenced), but you need to use the exception message to get a better understanding of why the exception was thrown. It looks here like you might have been trying to return a type that is different from the type specified by the method definition.

---

```
  Location:
    com/company/MyClass.getProperty(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object; @93: ireturn
```

This tells you where the exception occurred. You can tell that it happened in the class at `com.company.MyClass` at the method `getProperty`. It also tells you the parameter for the method, being `String`, and the return type, being `Object`. The `@93: ireturn` refers to the Java bytecode, which I will touch on later.

---

```
  Reason:
    Type integer (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'java/lang/Object' (from method signature)
```

This gives you a more specific reason for why the exception was thrown, and tells you exactly why. It tells you that an integer cannot be assigned to `Object` (this is probably because you are trying to return an `int` primitive, which does not inherit the `Object` type).

---

```
  Current Frame:
    bci: @93
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/company/MyClass', 'java/lang/String', 'java/lang/String' }
    stack: { integer }
```

This section tells you about the current frame. To go into that, we have to look into how Java actually works. When you compile some code in Java, it turns it into Java bytecode. This is similar to regular assembly, except that it can only run on the JVM, or Java Virtual Machine. On this virtual machine, `frame`s are created, and contain all of the local information. I am not completely experienced in the specifics of this information, but to my knowledge, the `bci` tag contains the current position in the bytecode. The `locals` tells Java what classes are loaded to the current scope, and the `stack` is exactly what it sounds like. It is basically just a list of a bunch of values.

---

```
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2b01 a600 0812 8da7 0007 2bb6 0090 4d2c
    0x0000010: b600 94ab 0000 0064 0000 0007 9a7f 0d13
    0x0000020: 0000 005f 9b27 5edf 0000 004b 0000 fc71
    0x0000030: 0000 0041 0023 a6ed 0000 005a 03b3 b10f
    0x0000040: 0000 0046 34ad f045 0000 0055 7a92 a99e
    0x0000050: 0000 0050 2ab6 0096 b02a b600 98ac 2ab6
    0x0000060: 009a b02a b600 9cb0 2ab6 009e b02a b600
    0x0000070: a0b0 2ab6 00a2 b0bb 0079 59bb 007b 59b7
    0x0000080: 007c 12a4 b600 822c b600 82b6 0086 b700
    0x0000090: 88bf
```

This tells you the raw bytecode of your program. This is what is being read by the JVM, and is quite closely related to assembly code. You can look at [Bytecode Viewer](https://bytecodeviewer.com/) to try and see the bytecode in a more human-readable form.

---

```
  Stackmap Table:
    same_frame(@10)
    same_locals_1_stack_item_frame(@14,Object[#101])
    append_frame(@84,Object[#101])
    same_frame(@89)
    same_frame(@94)
    same_frame(@99)
    same_frame(@104)
    same_frame(@109)
    same_frame(@114)
    same_frame(@119)
```

The Stackmap table essentially tells Java the expected types of variables and operands of a method during its execution. You can read more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37310409/4254252).

---

I hope this information gives you a good explanation of everything you were looking for. Don't hesitate to ask for a better explanation of anything.

Comment: It turned out to be javassist not autoboxing the returned value. I manage to workaround this limitation of Javassist.